# Create Outlook event and prevent forwarding

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I want to create calendar (outlook) events via the microsoft graph api and set some specific response options.
In the (windows) Outlook client I am able to enable/disable

- Request Response
- Allow new Time Proposals
- Allow Forwarding

In the documentation I can only find properties to enable/disable "Request Response" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events? but not the later ones.

The question is how to enable/disable **Time Proposals** and **Forwarding**?

I tried setting the sensitivity to "personal", "private" and "confidential" but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that through the extended property `DoNotForward`. This has the following property definition:

```
PropertySet: 00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046
Name: DoNotForward
Type: Boolean
```

[Here is an example](https://github.com/ivfranji/GraphManagedApi/blob/eaadf3ebd353e0410f3cee9abb0c925b7472f526/src/Microsoft.Graph.ManagedAPI.FunctionalTests/FunctionalTests/EventTestDefinition.cs#L118) I wrote for this.

Allow time proposal is:

```
PropertySet:00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046
Name: AppointmentNotAllowPropose
Type: Boolean
```

Using the ms-graph-sdk for dotnet the following code works:

```cs
var e = new Event()
{
    Subject = "subject",
    Start = new DateTimeTimeZone()
    {
        DateTime = dateTimeTimestamp1,
        TimeZone = "Europe/Berlin"
    },
    End = new DateTimeTimeZone()
    {
        DateTime = dateTimeTimestamp2,
        TimeZone = "Europe/Berlin"
    },
    SingleValueExtendedProperties = new EventSingleValueExtendedPropertiesCollectionPage()
    {
            new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty
            {
            Id = "Boolean {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name DoNotForward",
            Value = "true"
            },
            new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty
        {
            Id = "Boolean {00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x825A",
            Value = "true"
        }
    }
};
```

The `AppointmentNotAllowPropose` is referenced here by id, as setting the value by it's name somehow does not have an effect.

Comment: awesome, will try out. Is this anywhere documented?

Comment: I don't think all extended properties are documented, however, you can start from here just to get more info about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/cc9d955b-1492-47de-9dce-5bdea80a3323

Comment: The DoNotWard seems to work, AppointmentNotAllowPropose does not. Any ideas?

Comment: I was able to set AppointmentNotAllowPropose by its id. Using the name didn't work, I extended your answer.

Comment: Please be aware that Id isn't same in every mailbox, it is autogenerated for every mailbox and value is different meaning it will likely fail for you in case if you send same request to different mailbox on different DB. I can investigate directly on server side why name doesn't work if I get some extra time.

Comment: The  Id 0x825A value seems to be a global id: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxocal/61f0b1bb-f15d-4d88-bedb-c8b132994e1e

Comment: It's amazing this answer is still valid! It seems that if you create an item in Outlook where you disable forwarding it still used the above **Legacy** property.

Comment: Hi @IvanFranjic I have gone through your Managed API code and it was fantastic. Can you please help me how to send email with larger attachment using your code?

Comment: Thank you @IvanFranjic, DoNotForward works in my end